# how to know details for mysql in openshift?

Tags: mysql, openshift

I've tried a lot but in the end, i couldn't find the host for my openshift application, as i'm noob and plus openshift is meant for high level programmer there is no proper way to find it out, can you please let me know how to find it, as i'm losing my time without it...

Comment: Please supply a few more details.. we like to see some code efforts!

Comment: I'm a noob too, let's have coffee & study code tho ;- )

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can easily get this information if you look at the [OpenShift Environment Variables](https://www.openshift.com/developers/openshift-environment-variables)